# Convert time to other timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone, ruby-1.8

I have a datestring in this format
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[Z]

And i have a timezone string. for e.g "Asia/Kolkata"

Now i want to convert this date string into the timezone of the given timezone

for e.g. if the date is 2014-01-03T23:30:00Z , then in "Asia/Kolkata" timezone it will be 2014-01-04T05:00:00 .

I tried using Time library , but Time library does not seem to have any method which can convert to other timzone http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Time.html#method-c-mktime .

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.github.io/) gem.

```ruby
require 'tzinfo'

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Kolkata')
utc = DateTime.iso8601('2014-01-03T23:30:00Z')
local = tz.utc_to_local(utc)
```

Comment: Is tzinfo compatible with ruby 1.8 and rails 2.3. I tried using this gem but it displayed this error message "no such file to load -- tzinfo"

Answer (score 2):

If it just a ruby project without rails, also you do not want to install third party gems.
Then you have to do it yourself, the following is what I did:

```
  def convert_time_to_timezone(time, timezone)
    timezone_in_hours = timezone.to_i
    time_in_seconds = time.to_i
    time_in_seconds_in_timezone = time_in_seconds + timezone_in_hours*3600
    utc_time = Time.at(time_in_seconds_in_timezone).utc
    Time.new(utc_time.year, utc_time.month, utc_time.day, utc_time.hour, utc_time.min, utc_time.sec, "#{timezone}:00")
  end
```

Just provide time (e.g., Time.now) and timezone (e.g., "+11:00", or "-05:00")
it will return the time with the specified timezone.
example: 
call `convert_time_to_timezone(Time.now, "+11:00")` it will return something like

```
2017-05-31 18:17:13 +1100
```

If it has rails installed, then you can directly call `in_time_zone('"Central Time (US & Canada)"')`