# Convert string time UTC to time of timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get params `start_at` with value "16:00" or "4 pm". This is UTC time.

I have timezone and I need to calculate to time of timezone.

For example `start_at` is "16:00"

TimeZone = "Berlin", it is +1 hour.

Result will be 17:00.

How can I do it in Rails? Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it but this looks pretty promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577449/convert-time-to-other-timezone/44278155#44278155

Comment: `Time.find_zone("UTC").parse("16:00").in_time_zone("Europe/Berlin")`?

Answer (score -2):

please try this

```
started_at = "16:00"
time = started_at.to_time+1.hour
time = time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Gerhard: While that request is entirely appropriate, you should mark the answer as _Looks OK_, instead of recommending deletion, since it _is_ an answer. You can, of course, opt to downvote it if you feel it's not a _useful_ answer. ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).)