# Determine if a past date falls in the DST range using ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby

In ruby 2.4 [there was a change](https://wyeworks.com/blog/2016/6/22/behavior-changes-in-ruby-2.4) to how the `DateTime#to_time` method works. These changes have broken some existing code I had which checked if a given past datetime was in DST

The date below is in the [DST range for that year](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles). However, ruby is reporting that `dst? == false`. I'm pretty stumped here: without using rails how can I test the `dst?` value of a past datetime?

```
# 2016-07-27 00:00:00
unix_timestamp = 1469577600
time = Time.at(unix_timestamp).utc
pacific_time = Time.new(time.year, time.month, time.day, 0, 0, 0, "-08:00")
=> 2016-07-27 00:00:00 -0800
pacific_time.dst?
=> false
pacific_time.zone
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

If your local timezone is Pacific Time, then let Time assume it:

```
irb(main):001:0> unix_timestamp = 1469577600
=> 1469577600
time = Time.at(unix_timestamp).utc
irb(main):004:0> pacific_time = Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day)
=> 2016-07-27 00:00:00 -0700
irb(main):006:0> pacific_time.dst?
=> true
irb(main):007:0> pacific_time.zone
=> "PDT"
```

You can also get the local version of your UTC time:

```
irb(main):015:0> time_local = time.getlocal
=> 2016-07-26 17:00:00 -0700
irb(main):016:0> time_local.dst?
=> true
irb(main):017:0> time_local.zone
=> "PDT"
```

But, it may be a little brittle to depend on the local timezone without actually specifying it. If you need to display times in another timezone, different than UTC and different than the local one, then maybe [Rails' in_time_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone) and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214014/converting-time-in-utc-to-pacific-time) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue here is I need to calculate if a datetime in the past is in DST and the timezone of the datetime may or may not be in the local timezone of the machine. Is there a way to calculate if a past datetime is in DST when the timezone is different from the local timezone on the machine?